# Entity Framework - Store Procedure Return Value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

```
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

INSERT INTO WSUPPORTTEMP (FIRMRN, FPERSONNAME, SUPPORTTYPEID, FIRMEXPL, USERMAIL, ISENG, REASON ) 
OUTPUT      INSERTED.WRN
VALUES      (@firmrn, @requester, @supportType, @message, @email, @iseng, @reason)
END
```

I can not return output value with entity framework 6.

```
int x = _context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("i_NewSupportTicket @firmrn, @requester, @supportType, @message, @email, @iseng, @reason", sqParams).First();
```

Those are which I tried already, but I could not return value.

```
SqlParameter outParam = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@wrn",
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar
};
var y = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC @wrn = i_NewSupportTicket @firmrn, @requester, @supportType, @message, @email, @iseng, @reason", sqParams);
```

I got this exception.

> SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 't'
>   to data type int.

Where is the my fault ?

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: If you need `INSERTED.WRN` value to returned then you should assign it to `@wrn` parameter in the stored procedure and write `SELECT @wrn` in the stored procedure.

Comment: @Joel I added to question.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Actually, It was properly working with Dapper. I was need to convert my ORM to EF and this is happening.

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommand` method returns Integer value, while `@wrn` is of type NVarchar. That's why you are getting this error. You can try by changing DataType of `@wrn` parameter to SqlDbType.Int

Comment: @cpzz You are attempting dynamic SQL and SQL is trying to cast the parameter to an integer `value`. You are working with strings here in wrn

Comment: WRN data type is INT in Sql and I tried the change parameter type to SqlDbType.Int already. Those lines are which are I tried lastly. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Fixed. I should more carefull about sequence when I creating my SqlParameters. It was all about this. SP and C# parameter sequence must be same.